# Javascript OpenWindow not loading stylesheet not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

I have a document with a table and Print button. The print button calls a javascript function to generate a printable version in a new window. The printable version should load a stylesheet from the site. However the stylesheet does not load. And when I open the source from the newly opened window, although the stylesheet href -appears- correct, clicking on it does nothing. So clearly my browser doesn't recognise it as a proper href.

SO: Why is the link tag not being recognised as an href?

Here is the javascript function:

```
jQuery("div.jch-noise_records span.print_button a").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();                 
     var getpanel = document.getElementById("jch-noise_records");
     var MainWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=500,width=800');
     MainWindow.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n');
     MainWindow.document.write( '<html lang="en-US">\r\n<head>\r\n');
     MainWindow.document.write( '<title>Noise Records Report</title>\r\n');
     MainWindow.document.write( '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/jchwebdev-noise_by_hour/jchwebdev-noise_by_hour.css" type="text/css" media="all" />\r\n');
     MainWindow.document.write( '</head>\r\n');
     MainWindow.document.write( '<body>\r\n');                  
     MainWindow.document.write( getpanel.innerHTML);
     MainWindow.document.write( '\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n');
     MainWindow.document.close();
     MainWindow.document.focus();        
//   MainWindow.print();                     
     return true; 
});
```

And here is a bit of the html generated in the print window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Noise Records Report</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/jchwebdev-noise_by_hour/jchwebdev-noise_by_hour.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
</head>
<body>
<span class="close"><a title="Close" href="#">X</a></span><div class="jch_table_wrapper"><p class="header"><span class="report_date">2018-06-12 18:00</span><span class="report_title">Noise By The Hour (Checkbox Detail)</span><span class="report_ip">71.231.25.83</span></p><p class="header"><span class="report_query">For  date &gt;= 2018-01-01 AND date &lt;= 2018-05-31</span></p><table id="jch-noise_by_hour" class="jch-noise"><tbody><tr class="total"><td colspan="5">Total of  <span>151 </span> days tracked for <span></span> at <span> 12AM</span> from <span>01/01/2018</span> to <span>05/31/2018</span><br>
                                                                Average noise: <span>82.8dbA</span><br>
                                                                Total # of events detected: <span>12,153</span><br>                                                             
                                                                Average number of events/hour: <span>6</span></td></tr>
</tbody></table></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you put `http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/jchwebdev-noise_by_hour/jchwebdev-noise_by_hour.css` into your URL bar .. Does it take you to the CSS sheet? --  Is it redirecting to `https://` ?  What happens when you do just  `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/wp-content/plugins/jchwebdev-noise_by_hour/jchwebdev-noise_by_hour.css' type='text/css' media='all' />` ?

Comment: Why are you escaping the slashes in the URL? It is a string, not a regular expression, part of your problem may be escaping those `href=\'http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/jchwebdev-noise_by_hour/jchwebdev-noise_by_hour.css\'`

Comment: @Zak, if I paste the url into a browser it works fine. If I clink the <link rel=...> it does nothing.

Comment: @mpallansch I tried escaping the slashes only after trying it without. Either way it doesn't work. Again, it shows up as a syntax-highlighted link in Firefox, but you can't click on it and the linked CSS sheet doesn't load.

Comment: I edited the <link> to remove the escaped slashes. Made no difference with or without.

Comment: If you load up a dummy HTML page as the first param of your `window.open` call so that it loads a page from your domain (with the same HTTP[S] protocol and domain of your app), and then add the stylesheet to the head and swap out the body contents does that work? I'm wondering if the "" (empty string) URL is fighting you as being a different protocol/domain and thus blocking content somehow?

Comment: @scunliffe I added a dummy page into the first parameter of window.open and that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Although ***I'm guessing*** at why this is the issue, I wanted to put this answer here for visibility as **it seems to have worked** based on the comments on the question.

I believe the new popup window (or new tab depending on the user's settings) is not loading and rendering the linked CSS due to some sort of security/context issue.

Since the `window.open(url, name, params);` call you are making is passing in an empty string for the `url` and the `name` parameters I believe this is setting your new window to be in a different "protocol" or "domain" context than your opening page, AND the linked CSS file.

Someone like [@EricLaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126229/ericlaw) might be able to confirm this suspicion but I believe that `""` (empty string), `"about:blank"`, and `"javascript:"` trigger some special ~sandboxing~ when used for popups/iframes.

That all said, it appears that if you set the URL of your initial window.open() call to be an actual HTML page (it can be a dummy/stub) from your server... and then afterwards inject the CSS link you want and content to render in the body... it overcomes this issue.

Comment: Before I mark this as the accepted answer I want to do some research as to -why- your answer works. Back asap.

Comment: No worries, I too would like to know the exact reason why your original code didn't work but the revised code does. I'm hoping someone with intimate browser/networking/security details will be able to chime in.